# FileNotFoundException in File.php line 41

Tags: php, laravel-5

In laravel i am making an application that uploads a file and the user can download that same file.

But each time i click to download i get this error.
[image]

The view code:

```
<h5><a href="/download/{{$filesharing->fileName}}/{{$filesharing->fileType}}">Download</a></h5>
```

The route code:

```
Route::get('/download/{fileName}/{fileType}', 'FilesharingsController@download');
```

The controller code:

```
public function download($fileName, $fileType){
    $downloadPath = public_path(). '/assests/' . $fileName ;
    $headers =  array(
        'Content-Type: application/octat-stream',
        'Content-Type: application/pdf'
    );

    return Response::download($downloadPath, $fileName . '.' . $fileType, $headers);
}
```

Please not that when i upload a file i remove its extension.
Example: if i upload `'sample.pdf'` it is saved as `'sample'`.

I have no clue what is wrong as the path in the error is the correct path.
And the file exists in that path. Plz help

The folder Structure:
[image]

And the code used to upload the file is:

```
// Save uploaded file
    if ($this->request->hasFile('file') && $this->request->file('file')->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = public_path() . '/assests/';
        $fileName = $filesharing->fileName . '.' . $this->request->file('file')->guessClientExtension();
        $this->request->file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    }
```

Comment: But then i would have to change the url manually each time i upload a file

Answer (score 1):

Your $downloadPath is missing the file extension. The second parameter of Response::download is the file name **shown to the user**.

Your variable should look like this:

```
$downloadPath = public_path() . '/assets' . $fileName . '.' . $fileType;
```

Comment: Hi @Tim  is used this `$downloadPath = public_path(). '/assests/' . $fileName . '.' . $fileType ;` and for the response i used this `return Response::download($downloadPath,  $fileName . '.' . $fileType, $headers);`. It still didnt work, got the same error.

Comment: I see your point Tim but even in the public path i have named the folder incorrectly and it is 'assests'.

Comment: May we see a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: Tim i have added the folder structure and the upload code

Comment: Alright. I rolled back my answer. You are indeed saving the file WITH the file extension and not removing it, as you said.

I see nothing wrong with your code. I have no idea if this is environment specific to windows, but if Laravel says it can't find the file at the given path, chances are, there is no file at the given path with the given file name.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for help. I figured it out, the upload code that i was using was saving the file with the extension which was causing the problem. Many thanks for your help mate.